# Streaming data with old dates into bigquery partitioned table

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I'm trying to [stream data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) into bigquery partitioned table with nodejs client library:

```
async function streamData(rows) {
    try {
        await bigqueryClient
            .dataset(datasetId)
            .table(tableId)
            .insert(rows)

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

The data I'm trying to stream has an old date column, so I get this error:

> Value 1517143394540000 for field dateFieldName of the destination
>   table destinationTableId is outside the allowed bounds. You can only
>   stream to date range within 365 days in the past and 183 days in the
>   future relative to the current date.

Is there any way I can workaround this? Like both using the feature of streaming data on fly and partitioned table?

My end goal is to transfer data from an old database,
so the function `streamData()` located inside a loop and `rows` gets chunk of 1000 rows in each iteration.

Comment: This seems more like a feature request than something we can fix here - would you care to use the BigQuery issue tracker? (I'm wondering why you want to stream old data instead of batch it in, so make sure to tell the issue tracker why this is an important feature)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Because if I want to batch the data in, I would need to use a job with a query like `INERT INTO tableName VALUES (...), (....), .... ,(...)`. If rows contains like 50,000 records, I get error saying that the query is too large (there is a limit also on the queries size).

Comment: Use bq load, not DML